# Is there a way to select text squarely or vertically (not just in Preview)?

Tags: mac, text, web-browser, productivity, tweaks

I want to select text in the browser that is grouped in columns, it would be useful to be able to just select text (or objects) in a certain column, but selection is done horizontally only. I know that in html all content is organised hierarchically, but maybe there is a tweak or something available that would allow me to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's going to be entirely dependant on how the page is coded.

Comment: ...and *possibly* how the browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc.) is coded as well. So I am thinking this is "not likely."